# Can I ask a question on Stack Overflow if I know that it will take huge time to figure out the solution myself?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I have a problem in my web or Android app or I want to add a new feature and I know that it will take a huge amount of time to figure out the solution myself.

So can I ask the question on Stack Overflow to save my time?

Is Stack Overflow the right platform to ask this type of question?

If not, is there any other community where I can ask this type of question?

Or should I solve these problems on my own, if I know they will be solved, no matter how much time it takes?

Comment: Asking a question on SO should be your last resource, not your first.

Comment: is it is on topic and answerable in a Q&A format and not as a blog or project etc.

Comment: Are you going to send this months pay-check to the users that answer?

Comment: but when i read this link https://stackoverflow.com/tour it does not say that "it should be you last resource" @yivi

Comment: Let's put it this way: if asking a question on SO is your first resource, how is that question going to be well researched and documented?

Comment: of course not but we all may learn ...won't we?@rene

Comment: I don't want to learn how to do your job @amrit I'm too old for that.

Comment: i am not saying that it should be my first resource...what i am saying that after i have researched I found that if someone else help me then it will save a huge time...@yivi

Comment: @amrit people are volunteers here..They are ready to help _if you are stuck_ not ready to do leg work for you..

Comment: Yes, in my research I also found that if someone else hands me the solution to my problems I usually save a lot of work as well. If they do it for free, I also save a lot of money. $$$! Huge win.

Comment: this statement of yous clears my doubt to a little extent...but I am unable to figure out the difference between "stuck " and "do leg work" because all the questions we ask on stackoverflow is realted to work ..aren't they? any of us is not wasting time here..@SurajRao

Comment: of couse I do not want someone else to work for free and I am not asking for complete solution either@yivi

Comment: It is the difference between "I tried to add XYZ feature this way and am stuck here".. and "how can I add XYZ feature..any examples"

Comment: I got it ...Thanks!@SurajRao I will try not to put any question without complete effort of mine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, we're not a time saver for you.

But if you can ask a well formulated, decent researched and useful question the answers might save a lot of future visitors a lot of time.

And that benefits you as well.

Comment: I got the point ...Thanks! but unfortunately it seems like this question is going to be closed and won't help anyone in future to clear this doubt.

Comment: @amrit there are no close votes on your question and even it if is closed, with my upvoted answer it won't be automagically deleted either. This Q/A will help plenty of users that are willing to search for it, so thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @amrit: What makes you think it will be closed?

Comment: the number of downvotes made me think that there must be closed vote @Cerbrus

Comment: Anyways,Thanks everyone for making this clear.

Comment: @amrit on the main site downvotes = bad question, qnd are indeed often deleted. On meta downvotes = disagreement.  The fact people dont think your question should be answered 'no' doesn't  mean that it's a bad Q :). (That is also why downvotes on meta do not t rep :) )